# Add MOOCs section to CV

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Adding a section where you can display links to certificates earned in online classes on sites such as Coursera, Udacity, edx, etc.

Comment: To others wondering what a MOOC is (it's not a sick cow): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the need to specifically single out a MOOC. There's already a section reserved for Certifications, and the entry is free-text. That is, since you are not prompted to select from a list of already existing certificates (like Stack Exchange tags, for example) you can type in *any certificate you wish* in that area.

*Perhaps a better suggestion would be to simply add a hyperlink to the existing Certificate entry box for links relevant to the certificate.*

[image: Screenshot of certificates]

Comment: `Underwater Basket Weaving` after years of fruitless search, I have now found my future career.

Comment: @Pekka It's OT on Stack Overflow though... :(

Comment: **To Area 51!** ---